# DBCC unique cluster index corruption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am very new to the world of DB maintenance and recently ran to an issue that will appreciate your advice on.

I have a Database that the earliest solid backup file I can see without any corruption belongs to 7 months ago. I have run DBCC CHECK DB for my current database and I see there is issues with the indexes.

When I do a compare between what has changed in database I realized that someone added a “Unique cluster index” to a child table. (Not sure how to determine if it is a child table or parent table but I assume it is a child table)

My question is this: is it possible to break the records in child/parent tables relationship with applying “unique cluster index”?

I learned what cluster index and non-cluster index are but couldn’t find a solid document that tells me if applying unique cluster index can impact other related tables or not?

I appreciate your help in advanced and will be grateful if you can point me to any link to learn more about this subject.

Comment: You are asking whether the addition of this new index caused the corruption on different tables? Almost certainly no. Corruption can happen at any time due to issues at the storage layer. It is best practice to regularly check for this proactively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a new index, clustered or not, will not break existing foreign key relationships.

Be aware that creating a new unique index will of course fail if duplicate keys exist.